# Subtracting a string converted into a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a piece of code, which takes inputs in 24 hour time such as `23:59`, and prints how much time is left, so if it was 11:59 in the morning, it would return 12 hours.

I have been able to do this so far, but I cannot tell what is going wrong with this code right now:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def timeuntil(t): 
    time = t
    future = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M').replace(day = datetime.now().day, year = datetime.now().year, month = datetime.now().month)
    timeleft = (future - datetime.now())
    return timeleft
```

For your reference, `print(timeuntil(22:00))` returned `15:55:01.996377` when I ran it at 8:43 PM.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `eta`? Are you sure you don't mean `future - datetime.now()`?

Comment: @PacketLoss my bad i was renaming variables for clarity and I missed one. Good catch

Comment: What are you expecting it to output?

Comment: @PacketLoss I would like to get the hours minutes and seconds left until the time, so a datetime object would work perfect for this. As you can see, what it returns right now is fine as for format, but it is not correct right, as it is saying there is almost 16 hours to 10pm instead of 1 hour and 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue does not seem reproducible on my machine, even when defining the `datetime` objects to the time you specified. However It could be to do with `replace()` on your `datetime`.

There is really no need for this, and I think you would be best to create a `datetime` object correctly. Below addresses the problem and works as you have intended.

```
def timeuntil(begin):
    hour, minute = map(int, begin.split(':'))
    now = datetime.now()
    future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)
    return (future - now)

print(timeuntil("23:59"))
#7:35:06.022166
```

If you want to specify a different timezone to run this in, we can define our `datetime.now()` with a timezone, however we will need to strip this off to calculate `future - now`.

```
def timeuntil(begin):
    hour, minute = map(int, begin.split(':'))
    now = datetime.now(timezone('US/Pacific')).replace(tzinfo=None)
    future = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)
    return (future - now)
```

Comment: It is incredibly close, but im stuck on one thing. At the moment, it is doing UTC time. The inputs are going to be local time here, which is PST. Therefore, the times are all 8 hours off. Is there a way to make it so that datetime.now() is in PST? Or must we convert the input to UTC?

Comment: @AbidRasheed I have updated the answer to include `US/Pacific` timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the number of seconds until you reach the next day. I find this easier to follow with the time module and direct calculations.

```
import time
secs_in_day          = 60*60*24
secs_time_left_local = secs_in_day - (time.time() - time.altzone) % secs_in_day
hours                = int(secs_time_left_local // 3600)
minutes              = int((secs_time_left_local % 3600) // 60)
seconds              = int((secs_time_left_local % 3600) % 60)
print(f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}')
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not exactly what I wanted, I belive that you saw the "23:59" and got the whole next day thing, but I have updated the code to be a function so it is a little more clear as to what I am looking for.